How to set ssl context dynamically in resttemplate or restclient?
I have created a rest template with connection pooling and ssl context as Bean.. But I have a certificate which is have expiry.. so need to set ssl context again before the expiry of the certificate..
Since I need connection pooling.. I don't want to create rest template everytime.. is there any suggestion on how to do it?
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(getsslContext()); //need to update ssl context dynamically

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(30);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);

    RequestConfig requestConfig =
        RequestConfig.custom()
            .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(2))
            .build();

    HttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> requestFactory).build();
  }



You can try setting sslSocketFactory directly to HttpClient
HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            //...  
            .build();

